# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use package

Tags: python, module, importerror

We have a custom module that works perfectly on Windows 10, however, it fails on our Linux cloud instance (Debian Jessie) with ModuleNotFoundError.
The folder structure is the following:

```
|-dashboard-miner (git repo)
  |-setup.py
    |-dashboard_miner (the actual package)
```

Our setup.py is the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import dashboard_miner
import os

MODULE_BASEDIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'dashboard_miner')

try:
    long_description = open('README.md').read()
except IOError:
    long_description = ''

try:
    reqs = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt')).read()
except (IOError, OSError):
    reqs = ''

print(find_packages(where=MODULE_BASEDIR))

setup(
    name='dashboard_miner',
    version=dashboard_miner.get_version(short=True),
    description='Data mining utilities for True Cloud Dashboard',
    long_description=long_description,
    url='https://gitlabe1.ext.net.nokia.com/TCI/dashboard-miner',
    author='Hodossy, Szabolcs',
    author_email='szabolcs.hodossy@nokia.com',
    license='NOKIA Confidential',
    packages=find_packages(where=MODULE_BASEDIR),
    package_dir={'': 'dashboard_miner'},
    install_requires=reqs,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'miner=dashboard_miner.cli:main',
        ]
    },
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turned out that the `find_packages` function gives back relative paths, so it must be called from the proper folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file structure/ tree of `dashboard_miner (the actual package)` it has to contain a **init**.py so that it can be recognized by Python as a module.